# Filter list based on value existing in another list

Tags: python, list, loops, dictionary, for-loop

I have o first list A=

```
      [{'name': 'PASSWORD', 'id': '5f2496e5-dc40-418a-92e0-098e4642a92e'},
     {'name': 'PERSON_NAME', 'id': '3a255440-e2aa-4c4d-993f-4cdef3237920'},
     {'name': 'PERU_DNI_NUMBER', 'id': '41f41303-4a71-4732-a8a4-0eecea464562'},
     {'name': 'PHONE_NUMBER', 'id': 'ac24413b-bb8f-4adc-ada5-a984f145a70b'},
     {'name': 'POLAND_NATIONAL_ID_NUMBER',
      'id': '32c49d92-6d5f-408e-b41e-dfec76ceae6a'}]
```

and I have a second list B :

```
     [{'name': 'PHONE_NUMBER', 'count': '96'}]
```

I want to filter the first list based on the second in order to have the following list :

```
[{'name': 'PHONE_NUMBER', 'count': '96','id': 'ac24413b-bb8f-4adc-ada5-a984f145a70b'}.
```

I have used the following code but I dont get the right ouptut:

```
 filtered = []

for x,i in DLP_job[i]['name']:
    if x,i in ids[i]['name']:
        filtered.append(x)

print(filtered)
```

Comment: Does the 2nd list always have single value ?

Comment: No it can have more than one value

Comment: how does this even work? `DLP_job[i]['name']` returns a string, but when you do `for x,i in DLP_job[i]['name']` you are trying to assign a string it to two varaibles (x,i)? This won't even run.

Comment: Yes it does not work, it is why I am asking help on this

Comment: how did you end up coding this then? just loop over each list element, check if that element matches what you want to match and append it to the filtered dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution

```
A = [{'name': 'PASSWORD', 'id': '5f2496e5-dc40-418a-92e0-098e4642a92e'},
         {'name': 'PERSON_NAME', 'id': '3a255440-e2aa-4c4d-993f-4cdef3237920'},
         {'name': 'PERU_DNI_NUMBER', 'id': '41f41303-4a71-4732-a8a4-0eecea464562'},
         {'name': 'PHONE_NUMBER', 'id': 'ac24413b-bb8f-4adc-ada5-a984f145a70b'},
         {'name': 'POLAND_NATIONAL_ID_NUMBER',
          'id': '32c49d92-6d5f-408e-b41e-dfec76ceae6a'}]
B = [{'name': 'PHONE_NUMBER', 'count': '96'}]
    
print([{**x, **y} for x in A for y in B if y['name'] == x['name']])
```

Answer (score 0):

One way is to walk both lists, and wherever you have matching `name` keys, use the merger of the 2 dicts:

```
l1 =  [{'name': 'PASSWORD', 'id': '5f2496e5-dc40-418a-92e0-098e4642a92e'},
     {'name': 'PERSON_NAME', 'id': '3a255440-e2aa-4c4d-993f-4cdef3237920'},
     {'name': 'PERU_DNI_NUMBER', 'id': '41f41303-4a71-4732-a8a4-0eecea464562'},
     {'name': 'PHONE_NUMBER', 'id': 'ac24413b-bb8f-4adc-ada5-a984f145a70b'},
     {'name': 'POLAND_NATIONAL_ID_NUMBER',
      'id': '32c49d92-6d5f-408e-b41e-dfec76ceae6a'}]

l2 = [{'name': 'PHONE_NUMBER', 'count': '96'}, {'name': 'PERSON_NAME', 'count': '100'}]

result = []
for d2 in l2:    
    for d1 in l1:
        if d1['name'] == d2['name']:
            result.append({**d1,  **d2})

print(result)
```

```
[{'name': 'PHONE_NUMBER', 'id': 'ac24413b-bb8f-4adc-ada5-a984f145a70b', 'count': '96'},
{'name': 'PERSON_NAME', 'id': '3a255440-e2aa-4c4d-993f-4cdef3237920', 'count': '100'}]
```